# New Windows Install, some apps have internet, some don't

Tags: networking, windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, internet-connection

I reinstalled Win10 last week and after spending considerable time getting things installed realized that my VisualStudio Community had only partial internet. When browsing Nuget packages that worked, but when trying to download them it would fail.

Firefox, Internet Explorer and Edge have internet access, but Chrome doesn't. Slack also doesn't work.

Now the fun part. Sometimes it works.... If I restart the computer and launch Chrome, for about 10 seconds it works, then it stops and fails to connect to anything. I have tried using IP addresses without success, so it isn't just a DNS issue. I have checked proxy settings, but that isn't it either.

Any ideas other than reinstalling everything again? Someone suggested it could be part of the connection stack the developer used for one application vs another, how can I reinstall that if that is in fact the issue.

Comment: Great point, let me go install those from HP, it is a Z820 workstation

Comment: You are most welcome

Comment: I thought it was fixed, but it still is having trouble.

Comment: I have 2 network ports, one for internal traffic, one for external. I have tried alternating which is active. This is the only device on the network having these issues and it is only since reinstalling Windows that the trouble started.

Answer (score -1):

People think computer people don't have computer problems. I am here to say, that isn't true. Windows started having trouble, so I reinstalled. Trouble again, reinstalled. Trouble, new computer. Trouble, reinstall. This happened over the course of 2 weeks. I have started working from 5AM to 5PM so I can still have time to get some work done while messing with my computer.

Here was what happened in case it happens to you. Everything works fine, then Google Chrome stops working. Actually, it doesn't stop working all the time, if you restart your computer, it will work fine for about 25 - 30 seconds, then it won't work anymore. You will get timeout errors. Next try going to a non https website in Chrome and behold it working! That isn't really that helpful since 95% of websites now have https, but you can disable Cryptographic Services and have Chrome start working normally again.

Or you could just not use Chrome. Firefox and Internet Explorer still will work just fine..... Oh wait, did I mention how many new desktop applications use the Chrome engine? Problems will creep in from all sides in random applications and be sporadic in their appearance. An example is Visual Studio where I can use it's built in search tool to find "packages" to include in my software. The search works, the download doesn't. Slack, Postman, and other apps also use the Chrome engine.

Changing some network settings may make it start working again temporarily. Rebooting may do the same. Anything that might restart the Cryptographic Services may give you a false sense of satisfaction - don't give in! You are still in deep trouble!

Feel free to reinstall Windows. It will work just fine till the 1803 update is automatically installed. Even then, you may be OK depending on the other applications you have installed and hardware you have. If it happened to you once, plan on living with this nightmare till you find this link: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/s5S1uPI0kMc/PVBgVbx6DAAJ

I can't tell you if this is a permanent fix yet, but I can tell you that Chrome, and other apps, are working with Cryptographic Services enabled..... For now!